# How can I solve this 'no service found for - “org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer”' error with a statically built Qt?

Tags: qt, plugins, static-libraries

Hello in order to build static Qt for Windows, I followed the next article.

> http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW

Using Qt vesion – 5.2.0. Operating System- Windows7.
The problem is that it says – no service found for – “org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer” on building the project.

I searched the net, but no solution was useful. Maybe I’m not using them correctly because of some lack of knowledge of Qt infrastructure, but anyway if someone could give me some instructions of solving of this problem, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using statically Qt 5.2.1 OpenGL MinGW and had same problem (video wasn't playing with same "no service found"). In my case I solved the problem linking the static mediaplayer plugin (dsengine) in project. To do this I had to:

1) add in .pro file:

```
CONFIG += static
static:{
QTPLUGIN += dsengine
CONFIG += release
LIBS += -ldsengine
}
```

dsengine plugin is located in %QTDIR%/plugins/mediaservice/libdsengine.a

2) add somewhere in the code (around main.cpp):

```
#ifdef QT_STATIC
#include <QtCore/QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(DSServicePlugin)
#endif
```