# QMediaPlayer doesn't play anything on Ubuntu 16.04 / Qt 5.6

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtmultimedia

I'm using the official Qt 5.6 SDK on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I try to play an mp3 file I just get:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

The code is as simple as it gets:

```
mMediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(myMp3File));
mMediaPlayer->play();
```

This works on Android and it worked on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine before. What am I missing? All the required gstreamer (by documentation) stuff seems to be installed already by default, but it still doesn't work:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep gstream
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0                                 1.8.2-1~ubuntu1                                             amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                              1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0                             3.0.18-1                                                    amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64                       0.10.32.debian-1                                            amd64        Fluendo mp3 decoder GStreamer 1.0 plugin
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                             1.8.2-1~ubuntu1                                             amd64        libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64                       1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64                  1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer faad plugin from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64          1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer videoparsers plugin from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64                      1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps                       1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64                      1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64                      1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64                  1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                        1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                                   1.8.2-1~ubuntu1                                             amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                                 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64                  1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64                 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64                 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                              1.8.2-1~ubuntu1                                             amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer                1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1                                            amd64        GStreamer backend for LibreOffice
```

...and of course my sounds work otherwise perfectly.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582663/qt-no-service-found-for-org-qt-project-qt-mediaplayer-on-building-static

Comment: well, in 1404 probably you had gstreamer-0.10 and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

Comment: I've had this same problem on Lubuntu 16.04 with PyQt 5.9 and i'm still having this same issue on Lubuntu 17.10 (again with PyQt 5.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run your application with QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 to see plugin errors.

If you see errors about "libgstaudio-0.10.so.0", it's a GStreamer version problem. The official Qt binaries seems to need GStreamer 0.10.

Solutions I found :

- Use the libqt shipped with your distribution, using your package manager : It's the best solution I found, since it's built with the right GStreamer version. I use different chroot to make packages for distributions that embed different GStreamer versions.
- [Compile Qt from source to enable Gstreamer 1.0](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-330047) : Not tested
- Install Gstreamer 0.10 : I don't recommend this option, or use a chroot with an older distribution if you need it.

Comment: Yeah, seems to work with Qt 5.5 that comes with Ubuntu 16.04. This kinda sucks, because you are stuck with an old Qt version. Not a deal breaker in this case, however.

Comment: @grubshka For a Qt-newbie like me who is still having this problem, can i ask what specific package that i need to install in the first of you three solutions above? I've used `sudo apt-cache search libqt` but get a long list and i'm not sure what to install. I've tried `libqt5multimedia5` and `libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0`, is there another package that i need? Do i need to add more programming code to set up my player? Grateful for help!