# How to use gstreamer1.0 instead of 0.10 with Qt5.5?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer, qtmultimedia

I have a laptop and a computer and I want to test the [Media Player example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html) of Qt.
On my laptop, everything is working, but on my computer I have this message:

> no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

I have installed the [Multimedia Dependencies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html) but it's change nothing.
So I have try to find the missing packet by using synaptic and on the both computer, I have the same result by searching Gstreamer:
[image: gstreamer synaptic]
I have also create two file to compare with this command:

```
apt list | grep inst > apt_list.txt
# and
apt list | grep inst > apt_list_laptop.txt
tkdiff apt_list.txt apt_list_laptop.txt
```

I can't find what's missing, I ask your help to find it.

**Edit:**
I run the program with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and on the computer I have: `"QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/.../libgstmediaplayer.so"`
It's also said that it can't open `libgstaudio-0.10.so.0` but on the laptop it use the `1.0 version`.
And effectively, when I write:

```
ldd libgstmediaplayer.so
```

It's linked with gstreamer0.10 on my computer, and with 1.0 on my laptop

Comment: This might give a clue [QT.no service found for - “org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer” on building static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582663/qt-no-service-found-for-org-qt-project-qt-mediaplayer-on-building-static)

Comment: @MohammadKanan On both computer, I build dinamically, the Qt version and kit are the same.

Comment: both have Linux?

Comment: @MohammadKanan both have ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, it's because QtCreator use the library located in *`/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/mediaservice/`* but these libraries use the 0.10 version of gstreamer:

> **[Qt Multimedia Module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/whatsnew55.html)**:
>   Added GStreamer 1.0 support. Note that the default is still 0.10.

The library in the `libqt5multimedia5-plugins` package use the 1.0 version.  So, to launch the media player without *"no service"* message, I have compile by using command line:

```
qmake player.pro && make
```

By this way, qmake use the system library and not the libraries locate in the Qt folder.